# Converting ARB shaders to GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have found a pair of shaders written in ARB.I need help 
converting those in GLSL (1.2).I want to extend a project
that uses those ARB shaders, but learning GLSL I think it
would be easiser to habe GLSL shaders, that's why I need
a conversion.
I tried to convert them, but I know I am doing something wrong.
Could anyone help me explaining in depth
those ARB shaders and offer a conversion?

--- Original ARB v1.0 shaders ----

#### vertex shader

```
!!ARBvp1.0

OPTION ARB_position_invariant;

TEMP r0;

# get eye to vertex
ADD r0, vertex.position, -program.local[0];
# stuff for scaling the detail normal tex by distance
DP3 r0.w, r0, r0;
RCP r0.w, r0.w;
MUL r0.w, r0.w, 250000;
MIN r0.w, r0.w, 1;

# eye to vertex
MOV result.texcoord[1], r0;

# normal tex coord
MOV result.texcoord[0], vertex.texcoord[0];
# detail normal tex coord
MUL result.texcoord[3], vertex.texcoord[0], 5;
# not used currently, surface normal
#MOV result.texcoord[2].x, -r0.y;

END
```

#

#### fragment shader

```
!!ARBfp1.0

PARAM p0 = {-7, .5, 32, .2};
PARAM p1 = {0, 1, 0, .6};

TEMP r0;
TEMP r1;
TEMP r2;
TEMP r3;
TEMP r4;


# normal tex
TEX r0, fragment.texcoord[0], texture[0], 2D;
# detail normal tex
TEX r1, fragment.texcoord[3], texture[0], 2D;
#scale & bias to [-1, 1]
MAD r0, r0, 2, -1;
MAD r1, r1, 2, -1;
# scale detail normal tex by some factor based on eye distance
# maybe replace this with smoothed out mipmap levels
MUL r1, r1, fragment.texcoord[1].w;

# instead of per vertex normals it is all done in textures
#ADD r0, r0, fragment.texcoord[2];
ADD r0, r0, r1;
DP3 r0.w, r0, r0;
RSQ r0.w, r0.w;
MUL r0, r0, r0.w;

# normalize the eye to vertex vector
DP3 r2.w, fragment.texcoord[1], fragment.texcoord[1];
RSQ r2.w, r2.w;
MUL r2, fragment.texcoord[1], r2.w;

# bias towards an up vector when on edge/far away
POW r3.w, -r2.y, p1.w;
MOV r4, r0;
LRP r0, r3.w, r0, p1;
# specular needs to be biased less, or not at all
LRP r4, r3.w, r0, r4;

# vertex to eye * normal, clamped
DP3_SAT r2.w, -r2, r0;

# get the half angle vector and normalize
ADD r3, -r2, program.local[3];
DP3 r3.w, r3, r3;
RSQ r3.w, r3.w;
MUL r3, r3, r3.w;
# half angle * normal
DP3_SAT r0.w, r3, r4;
# specular exponent
POW r0.w, r0.w, p0.z;

# fresnel = (1 + eye-normal dot product) ^ -7    (an approximation)
# could probably approximate with 1 - dot(vertex to eye, normal)
ADD r3.w, 1, r2.w;
POW r3.w, r3.w, p0.x;

# prepare the reflection texture coords (uses n.x and n.z as an offset)
MOV r0.y, r0.z;
# scale and bias screen position to get reflection texcoords - could do this in vertex program?
MAD r1, fragment.position, program.local[0], program.local[1];
# offset coords by normal, scaled down by distance (extra 10x factor stored in program.local[0].z)
RCP r1.z, r1.z;
MAD r1, r0, r1.z, r1;
# offset reflection lookup
TEX r1, r1, texture[1], 2D;

# specular
MUL r3.xyz, r0.w, program.local[4];
# reflection * fresnel
MAD r1, r1, r3.w, r3;
# add water color * (1 - fresnel)
ADD r3.w, 1, -r3.w;
MAD result.color, program.local[2], r3.w, r1;

END
```

#

My atempt to convert them:

///////// vertex shader //////////

```
//#version 120

//OPTION ARB_position_invariant;

//var locala vertex shader
uniform vec4 cameraPos; //program.local[0]

//var vertex + fragment shader

varying vec4 waterTex0; //
varying vec4 waterTex1; //eyepos
varying vec4 waterTex2; //
varying vec4 waterTex3; //

void main(void)
{

//TEMP r0;
vec4 eyePos;

// get eye to vertex
//ADD r0, vertex.position, -program.local[0];
eyePos = gl_Vertex - cameraPos;

// stuff for scaling the detail normal tex by distance
//DP3 r0.w, r0, r0;
//RCP r0.w, r0.w;
//MUL r0.w, r0.w, 250000;
//MIN r0.w, r0.w, 1;
eyePos.w = dot(eyePos, eyePos);
eyePos.w = min(1.0 / eyePos.w * 250000, 1.0);


// eye to vertex
//MOV result.texcoord[1], r0;
waterTex1 = eyePos;

// normal tex coord
//MOV result.texcoord[0], vertex.texcoord[0];
waterTex0 = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

// detail normal tex coord
//MUL result.texcoord[3], vertex.texcoord[0], 5;
waterTex3 = gl_MultiTexCoord0 * 5; 

// not used currently, surface normal
//MOV result.texcoord[2].x, -r0.y;

//END

//transformam pozitia vertexilor
//gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

/////////////// fragment shader //////////////

```
//#version 120

//var locale fragment shader
//TEMP r0;
//TEMP r1;
//TEMP r2;
//TEMP r3;
//TEMP r4;


uniform vec4 texScale1; //program.local[0]
uniform vec4 texScale2; //program.local[1]
uniform vec4 waterColor; //program.local[2]
uniform vec4 lightDir; //program.local[3]
uniform vec4 specularColor; //program.local[4]

uniform sampler2D normalTex;
uniform sampler2D reflTex; 

//var vertex + fragment shader
varying vec4 waterTex0; //
varying vec4 waterTex1; //eyepos
varying vec4 waterTex2; //
varying vec4 waterTex3; //

void main(void)
{

//PARAM p0 = {-7, 0.5, 32, 0.2};
const vec4 p0 = vec4(-7.0, 0.5, 32.0, 0.2);
//PARAM p1 = {0, 1, 0, .6};
const vec4 p1 = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.6);

// normal tex
//TEX r0, fragment.texcoord[0], texture[0], 2D;
vec4 vNormT = texture2D(normalTex, vec2(waterTex0));

// detail normal tex
//TEX r1, fragment.texcoord[3], texture[0], 2D;
vec vDetailNormT = texture2D(normalTex, vec(waterTex3));

//scale & bias to [-1, 1]
//MAD r0, r0, 2, -1;
vNormT *= 2;
vNormT = clamp(vNormT, -1, 1);
//MAD r1, r1, 2, -1;
vDetailNormT *= 2;
vDetailNormT = clamp(vNormT, -1.0, 1.0); //clamp la [-1, 1]

// scale detail normal tex by some factor based on eye distance
// maybe replace this with smoothed out mipmap levels
//MUL r1, r1, fragment.texcoord[1].w;
vDetailNormT *= waterTex1.w;

/// instead of per vertex normals it is all done in textures
/// ADD r0, r0, fragment.texcoord[2];
//ADD r0, r0, r1;
//DP3 r0.w, r0, r0;
//RSQ r0.w, r0.w;
//MUL r0, r0, r0.w;
vNormT += vDetailNormT;
vNormT = normalize(vNormT);

// normalize the eye to vertex vector
//DP3 r2.w, fragment.texcoord[1], fragment.texcoord[1];
//RSQ r2.w, r2.w;
//MUL r2, fragment.texcoord[1], r2.w;
vec4 vEyePosN = normalize(waterTex1);

// bias towards an up vector when on edge/far away
//POW r3.w, -r2.y, p1.w;
//MOV r4, r0;
//LRP r0, r3.w, r0, p1;
vec4 vHalfAngle = vec4(0);
vHalfAngle.w = pow(-vEyePosN.y, p1.w); //in loc de r3.w

vec4 vNormTtt = vNormT;
//LRP R0, R0, R1, R2: is R0*R1+(1-R0)*R2
//vNormT = vec4(vNormT * vHalfAngle.w) + vec4(p1 * (1.0 - vHalfAngle.w));
vNormT = mix(vNormT, p1, vHalfAngle.w); //functie interpoalre liniara

// specular needs to be biased less, or not at all
//LRP r4, r3.w, r0, r4;
//vNormTtt = vec4(vNormT * vHalfAngle.w) + vec4(vNormTtt * (1.0 - vHalfAngle.w));
vNormTtt = mix(vNormT, vNormTtt, vHalfAngle.w);

// vertex to eye * normal, clamped
//DP3_SAT r2.w, -r2, r0;
// ???
vEyePosN.w = clamp(dot(-vEyePosN, vNormT), 0.0, 1.0); //DP3_SAT <=> dot() si clamp()


// get the half angle vector and normalize
//ADD r3, -r2, program.local[3];
//DP3 r3.w, r3, r3;
//RSQ r3.w, r3.w;
//MUL r3, r3, r3.w;
vHalfAngle = lightDir - vEyePosN;
vHalfAngle = normalize(vHalfAngle);

// half angle * normal
//DP3_SAT r0.w, r3, r4;
vNormT.w = clamp(dot(vHalfAngle, vNormTtt), 0.0, 1.0);

// specular exponent
//POW r0.w, r0.w, p0.z;
vNormT.w = pow(vNormT, p0.z);

// fresnel = (1 + eye-normal dot product) ^ -7    (an approximation)
// could probably approximate with 1 - dot(vertex to eye, normal)
//ADD r3.w, 1, r2.w;
//POW r3.w, r3.w, p0.x;
vHalfAngle.w = vEyePosN.w + 1.0;
vHalfAngle.w = pow(vHalfAngle.w, p0.x);

// prepare the reflection texture coords (uses n.x and n.z as an offset)
//MOV r0.y, r0.z;
vNormT.y = vNormT.z;

// scale and bias screen position to get reflection texcoords - could do this in vertex program?
//MAD r1, fragment.position, program.local[0], program.local[1];
//trebuie sa mut acesata linie in vertex shader, sa vad cum fac ...?
vDetailNormT = gl_Position * texScale1;
vDetailNormT += texScale2;

// offset coords by normal, scaled down by distance (extra 10x factor stored in program.local[0].z)
//RCP r1.z, r1.z;
//MAD r1, r0, r1.z, r1;
vDetailNormT.z = 1 / vDetailNormT.z;
vNormT *= vDetailNormT.z;
vDetailNormT += vNormT;

// offset reflection lookup
//TEX r1, r1, texture[1], 2D;
vDetailNormT = texture2D(reflTex, vDetailNormT);

// specular
//MUL r3.xyz, r0.w, program.local[4];
vHalfAngle.xyz = specularColor * vNormT.w;
// reflection * fresnel
//MAD r1, r1, r3.w, r3;
vDetailNormT *= vHalfAngle.w;
vDetailNormT += vHalfAngle;

// add water color * (1 - fresnel)
//ADD r3.w, 1, -r3.w;
//MAD result.color, program.local[2], r3.w, r1;
vHalfAngle.w = 1.0 - vHalfAngle.w;
waterColor *= vHalfAngle.w;

gl_FragColor = waterColor + vDetailNormT;

//END

}
```

Comment: As a note, you probably want to convert to a modern version of GLSL. 1.2 is from 2006, and they're on 4.3 now.

Comment: ok, I understand.Could anyone help me clarify/understand the ARB code,I mean the logics behind it, because what ARB code instruction do I found already, but I want to understand the logics. Hope this will help me convert them manually.

Comment: I would just ignore the ARB shaders and focus on learning GLSL. If you add the translation from ARB in the process you are trying to learn to languages simultaneously. That complicates things.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, the Horrible Old Days.

It looks to me that the geometry being rendered has two surface normal texture maps, one 'normal' and one 'detail' presumably higher-res for close ups.

The vertex shader calculates the distance from the eye and scales it into a fraction of 250000, presumably the size of the world or far distance.

The fragment shader gets the surface normal from the texture map, then adds a weighted fraction of the nearest detail surface normal using the distance value calculated by the vertex shader. This ensures that at a distance the surface normal doesn't keep changing drastically as the object moves.

Then there's a standard ambient-diffuse-specular lighting calculation, although with an extra tweak at the comment "Bias towards an up vector"

The interesting bit starts with "fresnel = (1 +" AFAIK that's used for calculating the distortion caused by viewing an object underwater. (Or an object in air if you're underwater.) The use of fragment position suggests there is a screen-resolution sized reflection/environment map.

The "offset reflection lookup" presumably gives the color of the fragment, which is then multiplied by the A-D-S lighting value.

As Grimmy suggests, you will almost certainly be better off figuring out what you want to achieve and writing directly in GLSL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to have the exact results as in the ARB shaders, that's why I want to translate them.Thank you Hugh Fisher!